# jQuery draggable and droppable prevent drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using this code to drag elements from one container into another. I just want to detect drop event and then perform my own action (**I dont want item to be dropped automatically!**). With current code, this work well. However items are not sortable in drop_container. If I add sortable on drop_container (what is currently commented out in code example), then items are sortable in drop_container, however item is automatically droped into drop_container which I dont want. How could I solve this?

```js
$("#drag_container li").draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#drop_container",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
});

var droppable = $("#drop_container").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('drop')
    var _item = jQuery(ui.draggable).clone(true,true).appendTo(droppable);
   
  }
})/*.sortable({
  helper: "clone",
})*/;
```

```css
#drag_container li {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}

#drop_container {
  clear: both;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draggable/1.0.0-beta.11/draggable.min.js"></script>

<ul id="drag_container">
  <li id="one">One</li>
  <li id="two">Two</li>
  <li id="three">Three</li>
  <li id="four">Four</li>
  <li id="five">Five</li>
  <li id="six">Six</li>
</ul>

<div id="drop_container">Drop Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing sortable inside draggable

```js
$("#drag_container li").draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#drop_container",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
});

var sortable = $("#drop_sortable").sortable({
  helper: "clone",
})

$("#drop_container").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('drop')
    var _item = jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(sortable);
  }
})
```

```css
#drag_container li {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}

#drop_container {
  clear: both;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draggable/1.0.0-beta.11/draggable.min.js"></script>

<ul id="drag_container">
  <li id="one">One</li>
  <li id="two">Two</li>
  <li id="three">Three</li>
  <li id="four">Four</li>
  <li id="five">Five</li>
  <li id="six">Six</li>
</ul>

<div id="drop_container">
  Drop Here
  <ul id="drop_sortable"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this but drop event is still fired after sortable (which I dont want). I only want drop event after drop. could  this be achieved?